# Force-based graph: 3D edge collision

Tags: game-physics

Imagine a moving 3D force-based graph with colliding edges. How easy it is to write a specific physics engine for calculating edge (strings, ropes) collision so that every object would behave like in a real world? Strings should bend, nodes should repulse each other, etc. Accuracy beyond visual recognition as "looks real" doesn't matter, it's a game.

Edit: Maybe I forgot to mention, that approximating edges as multi-segmented strings is the only option I can think of.

And yes, would it be possible to scale such physics to hundreds or thousands of edges?

Comment: +1 nice question, I'm making a game at school and this could help! ;) Still don't understand why people upvote trivial questions.

Comment: This would be a great question for gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I solved this question myself at [game development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/how-to-detect-and-collide-two-elastic-strings/7572#7572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physics engines have a lot of minor details in them to ensure that the end result 'looks real'.  I would not recommend coding one unless you are looking to learn.  Start with something that works and is free, such as [Bullet Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(software)).

Besides, then you get to spend less time coding a physics engine and more time coding a game.  Win-Win.

EDIT:

If you really want to program your own however, take a look at [Real Time Collision Detection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607323), which is pretty definitive information on the subject.

Comment: Thank you. I am not against using libraries for the task. The only restriction is that the game is in Scala. Bullet Physics has nice features, but I don't really know, how should I implement colliding edges using it.